# For Loop Rock Paper Scissors Game [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript

I'm making a Rock, Paper, Scissors game in JavaScript for a class. My teacher wants me to use a for loop to take out repeated turns. Along with that it needs to go for 10 games in the for loop, I need to print out the score after each round, and then once the game is finished I have to print the total score.

Please help I have no idea what to do. I've been trying for the last 4 hours but I can't find any answers to my specific problem.

```js
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

// User choice
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
if (! userChoice) {
    // User choice was undefined
    document.write("<p>Player 1, you cheated! Refresh this screen and fight like a man.</p>");
} else {
    // Display user choice
    document.write("<p>Player 1:" + " " + userChoice + "</p>");
}
// Computer choice
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}

// Display computer choice
document.write("<p>Computer:" + " " + computerChoice + "</p>");
// Compare user choice vs computer choice
var compare = function(choice1,choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return "It's a tie!";
    }
    if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            // rock wins
            return "You win!";
        } else {
            // paper wins
            return "You lose! Try again.";
        }
    }
    if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            // paper wins
            return "You win!";
        } else {
            // scissors wins
            return "You lose! Try again.";
        }
    }
    if (choice1 === "scissors") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            // rock wins
            return "You lose! Try again.";
        } else {
            // scissors wins
            return "You win!";
        }
    }
};
// Run the compare function
var results = compare(userChoice,computerChoice);
// Display results
document.write("<br><hr><b>Results: </b>" + results);

}
```

Comment: Nice exercise! What is exactly the problem you're encountering?

Comment: Before your for loop, you can initialize 3 variables to 0. Win/lose/tie. After each result, add one to the proper variable. After the for loop is finished, print out the final value of the three variables.

Comment: What's your problem though? Is it that the results don't get written until you play all 3 rounds?

Comment: @Brenex Here's what I tried. I'm still having no luck, I must be doing it wrong. Here's my code: https://pastebin.com/QAUYGaBx

Comment: @BrianSamu, Try moving the increment before the return statement. Anything after the return is unreachable. I'm guessing you were getting 0 for all variables? Also, as a shorthand, you can use win+=1 instead of win = win + 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue in the pastebin you commented is  you are trying to add the score AFTER you have already returned a value. Code after the return is unreachable. You need to add the value before. Also, you can just you wins+=1 as a small shorthand. :)

```
var win = 0;
var loss = 0;
var tie = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

// User choice
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
if (! userChoice) {
    // User choice was undefined
    document.write("<p>Player 1, you cheated! Refresh this screen and fight like a man.</p>");
} else {
    // Display user choice
    document.write("<p>Player 1:" + " " + userChoice + "</p>");
}
// Computer choice
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}

// Display computer choice
document.write("<p>Computer:" + " " + computerChoice + "</p>");
// Compare user choice vs computer choice
var compare = function(choice1,choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        tie+=1;
        return "It's a tie!";
    }
    if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            // rock wins
            win+=1;
            return "You win!";
        } else {
            // paper wins
            loss+=1;
            return "You lose! Try again.";
        }
    }
    if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            // paper wins
            win+=1;
            return "You win!";
        } else {
            // scissors wins
            loss+=1;
            return "You lose! Try again.";
        }
    }
    if (choice1 === "scissors") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            // rock wins
            loss+=1;
            return "You lose! Try again.";
        } else {
            // scissors wins
            win+=1;
            return "You win!";
        }
    }
};
// Run the compare function
var results = compare(userChoice,computerChoice);
// Display results
document.write("<br><hr><b>Results: </b>" + results);

}
document.write("<br/>Final Results: W-"+win+"; L-"+loss+"; T-"+tie+";");
```

Comment: Oh! I see what you're saying. That makes so much sense now. Many thanks to you Brenex. That really helped me out, and now I know for next time haha.

Comment: @BrianSamu I'm glad you got it figured out! If my answer helped you out, please accept it as the answer. :) Good luck in school!